# Will php token_get_all() without TOKEN_PARSE ever throw ParseError?

Tags: php, tokenize

php `token_get_all()`, when called with `TOKEN_PARSE` flag, will throw `ParseError` if it encounters bad syntax.

Without the `TOKEN_PARSE` flag, I have not seen it throw anything.
I am working without TOKEN_PARSE because I am dealing with these problems myself, and it is faster this way.

Is this reliable? If not, is there any php code I could throw at it to make it throw an error or exception?

I want to know this for a parser I am working on:

- If an error or exception never occurs, I can drop the try/catch.
- If an error or exception can occur, and I keep the try/catch, I want to add test coverage, which needs a reproducible example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `TOKEN_PARSE` flag `token_get_all()` can throw an exception like `Parse error: syntax error` when parsing an invalin php file

Comment: I know that. My question is about if I am _not_ using that flag.